# Passing values between class and instance

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, python-3.x

```
class MyClassA(object):
    def __init__(self):
        entry = input("Insert a value ::: ")
        b = MyClassB(entry) #To pass the variable entry to class MyClassB
        c = MyClassC() #Initializied MyClassC to be ready for receive the value p
        self.x = b.f #To get back the value f from MyClassB
        print(self.x)
        self.x1 = c.p #To get back the value f from MyClassC
        print(self.x1)

class MyClassB(object):
    def __init__(self, M):
        self.f = M * 10 # f will contain (the value entry from MyClassA *10)
        c = MyClassC(self.f) #To pass variable f to class MyClassC

class MyClassC(object):
    def __init__(self,passedVar):
        self.p = passedVar + 0.1 # p will contain (the value entry from MyClassB + 0.1)

h = MyClassA()
```

Above is my sample code, first of all it will ask for a value and store it into variable named `entry`.
Then the second class named `MyClassB` will recover the value inside `entry`, after processing the entry value, a new one will be stored into new variable named `f` which will be passed to third class named `MyClassC` then also back to first class.
Finally the third class does some processing of the `f` value and stores it into yet another variable `p`.

That's how my code should work when the user runs the program, and this is what it would look like:

```
Insert a value ::: 9 (assume the user typed 9 here)
```

so the output should be:

```
90
90.1
```

Unfortunately my problem is that passing the value from `MyClassC` to `myClassA` doesn't work.
It says I must pass it two argument from the first class but it'a going to get the value after executing the 2st class.
I think that I have problem with initializing instances, could someone correct my code to work the way I described?

Comment: added answer, you are missing an input ..

Comment: You shouldn't use `__init__` for input/output.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're having is because there are two independent instances of `MyClassC` being created, one in `MyClassA.__init__()` and a separate one in `MyClassB.__init__()`.

The easy way to fix it — not necessarily the best — would be to make `MyClassB.__init__()` store the `MyClassC` instance it creates in yet another instance attribute, and then refer to the attribute of *that* object when you want to retrieve the value of `p`.

Here's what I mean:

```
class MyClassA(object):
    def __init__(self):
        entry = input("Insert a value ::: ")
        b = MyClassB(entry)  # To pass the variable entry to class MyClassB
####### c = MyClassC()  # Initializied MyClassC to be ready for receive the value p
        self.x = b.f  # To get back the value f from MyClassB
        print(self.x)
        self.x1 = b.c.p  # To get back the value p from MyClassC instance created in MyClassB
        print(self.x1)

class MyClassB(object):
    def __init__(self, M):
        self.f = M * 10  # f will contain (the value entry from MyClassA *10)
        self.c = MyClassC(self.f)  # Pass variable f to class MyClassC and save instance

class MyClassC(object):
    def __init__(self, passedVar):
        self.p = passedVar + 0.1 # p will contain (the value entry from MyClassB + 0.1)

h = MyClassA()
```

Answer (score 0):

In line

```
 c = MyClassC()
```

it should be

```
 c = MyClassC(b.f)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could set the value `p` to the class `MyClassC`

```
class MyClassC(object):
    def __init__(self, passedVar):
        MyClassC.p = passedVar + 0.1
```

but keep in mind that this situation can happen

```
class T(object):

    def __init__(self, x):
        T.x = x
if __name__ == '__main__':
    t1 = T(3)
    print t1.x, T.x
    t1.x = 1
    print t1.x, T.x
    t2 = T(2)
    print t1.x, t2.x, T.x
# output: 
3 3
1 3
1 2 2
```