# Python : Passing values between class and instance and methods

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, python-3.x

A few days ago, I asked about passing values between instances of classes here is my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36575062/passing-values-between-class-and-instance)
That problem was easy to fix especially the movement.
But now I can't pass objects between methods.

Example code:

```
class MyClassA(object):
    def function1(self):
        entry = input("Insert a value ::: ")
        b = MyClassB(entry) #To pass the variable entry to class MyClassB
        d = MyClassB()
        d.function2()
        c = MyClassC(b.k) #Initializied MyClassC to be ready for receive the value p
        self.x = d.f #To get back the value k from MyClassB function2()
        print(self.x)
        self.x1 = c.p #To get back the value k from MyClassC
        print(self.x1)

class MyClassB(object):
    def __init__(self,M):
        self.f = M
        self.k = 0
    def function2(self):
        self.k = self.f * 10 # k will contain (the value entry from MyClassA *10)
        c = MyClassC(self.k) #To pass variable k to class MyClassC

class MyClassC(object):
    def __init__(self,passedVar):
        self.p = passedVar + 0.1 # p will contain (the value entry from MyClassB + 0.1)

h = MyClassA()
h.function1()
```

Otherwise whenever i try to work with instanace it gonna work right but between methods not that such fixed.
as last time this my code should give this way of result :

```
Insert a value ::: 9 (assume the user typed 9 here)
```

so the output should be:

```
90
90.1
```

here my code complation say

```
d = MyClassB()
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Any way I can fix my code > It doesn't need to work only with instances; I need some function inside some class

Comment: What is d1 supposed to equal? funciton2 doesn't return anything...

Comment: i type it wrong ... check now !!

Comment: Your __init__ method for MyClassB is: def __init__(self,M): however when you create the instance, you don't provide an argument for 'M'

Comment: **-1** - Your error message describes the problem exactly. You need to pass an argument to MyClassB, like you did on the line above

Comment: @user6056648 when make my operation of MyclassB without function2 its work fine then the argument M passed correctly but in this case when there function inside its stuck !!
any way could you show me you try ?

Comment: @mohamed-bouabid, no it still doesn't work if you simply remove function2 from MyClassB. You will still have a TypeError because of the 4th line of your module d = MyClassB() That is where the exception occurs because you are calling MyClassB without providing an argument into init. Just need to pass an argument there, even 0 will work. Then of course, you'll also have an issue with a NameError for d1 since d1 isn't defined or created anywhere.

Comment: @user6056648 yes i correct that d1 removed , i type it wrong.
some problem i try many way with those functions but no way the reason am here searching for support, could you give me your try how could you fix this code issue ??

Comment: If your problem is not specific to any Python version, don't specify which version it is in the tags.  If it is a problem only in Python-2.7, remove the Python-3.x tag.  If it is a problem only in Python-3.x, remove the Python-2.7 tag.  If it is a problem in both, remove both tags.  If it is a problem in neither, ... don't ask the question, but that's sort of obvious :]

Comment: i try this code on python 2.7 sir

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass something to the constructor for MyClassb()...

Comment: Correctly, __init__ is not a constructor. The object has already been created by the time __init__ is called, hence the ability to pass it to itself in the method.

Comment: @kpie : i know that need something for my constructor but still weird about that, and how could the block of code gonna be !!!
can you provid me a way ?

Comment: One solution that works well in most languages is to pass a dictionary as the argument such that a single function can handle a variety of inputs.

Comment: @kpie i didn't understand you well, could you explain your description by codes block?

Comment: Because myClassb.__init__ takes self and m, you must pass m to your calls to the instance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok My problem is

`d = MyClassB()
 d.function2()`

Statu is Fixed now, i got the way !!!
Correct code is this way :

```
class MyClassA(object):
    def function1(self):
        entry = input("Insert a value ::: ")
        b = MyClassB(entry) #To pass the variable entry to class MyClassB
        b.function2()
        c = MyClassC(b.k) #Initializied MyClassC to be ready for receive the value p
        self.x = b.f #To get back the value k from MyClassB function2()
        print(self.x)
        self.x1 = c.p #To get back the value k from MyClassC
        print(self.x1)

class MyClassB(object):
    def __init__(self,M):
        self.f = M
    def function2(self):
        self.k = self.f * 10 # k will contain (the value entry from MyClassA *10)
        c = MyClassC(self.k) #To pass variable k to class MyClassC

class MyClassC(object):
    def __init__(self,passedVar):
        self.p = passedVar + 0.1 # p will contain (the value entry from MyClassB + 0.1)

h = MyClassA()
h.function1()
```